# layers of the OSI model

Tags: networking, layer, osi

I know this question may not make sense to many of you, but I still want to learn.

I want to know that when we want to send a message from one device to another device from another network, are all the OSI layers is going to be handled by our computer?

Or there are specific layers that our computer can process, other layers can be processed by switches, routers, etc.

Your kind support is highly appreciated.

Comment: this is not programming related.

Comment: Nothing implements the OSI model. The IP Services model is closer to the real world, but it is still just a model, and things often differ from the model.

Answer (score -1):

The OSI layer is a model to represent 7 layers of the data contain in a packet. This model is a representation only. There is the TCP/IP model that is the one used for almost all TCP/IP communications.

The devices Switch for example work on the layer 2 of the OSI model, this means they can read the MAC address of the packet that is located on the 2nd layer.

Routers for example they can read up to the layer 3 of the OSI model, meaning they can read IP addresses of the package to make routing decisions.

Hubs on the other hand are layer 1 devices, they just forward the information they get to all ports.

Comment: The word is 'packet', not 'package'. What do you mean '*almost* all TCP/IP communications'?

Comment: TCP/IP is used for most of the communications, we have UDP, IPX, RS-485, BacNet among others. The most used is TCP/IP.

Comment: TCP/IP is the name of the entire suite, including TCP and UDP. TCP is the name of a transport protocol. You are mixing them up. The TCP/IP model, to the extent that it is valid, is used for *all* TCP/IP communications, by definition, and "TCP/IP communications" does not include IPX, RS-285, BacNet, etc. And the OSI model covers operating system layers, not 'layers of data': and it does not apply to TCP/IP at all.  Your answer is confused.

Comment: @user207421 What part of my answer is incorrect? There is a model that is called TCP/IP (it have 4 layers). Because for reference purposes every manufacturer of communication devices references the OSI model not the TCP/IP model my response was based on the OSI model. The model represent the encapsulation and encapsulation of packages and the information that is available on each layer.

Comment: 1.  ‘Package’. 2. TCP/IP has 5 layers. 3. Everything else I said above.